# Can't undestand $\frac{d}{dx} \left(c + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) \right)$

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to solve $\frac{d}{dx} \left(c + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) \right)$ but I'm stuck at the part that uses the chain rule to find the derivative of $\cos(2x)$.

My solution considers that $\frac{d}{dx} (\cos(2x))$ is $-2 \cdot \cos(2x)$, but Wolfram Alpha's solution is diferent. Why?

(http://s21.postimage.org/snx1vcrs7/Wolfram_Alpha_derivative_of_x2_12cos2x_c_2013.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please be careful with parentheses.  One can read $1/2\cos(2x)$ as $\frac 12 (\cos(2x))$ or as $\frac 1{2\cos(2x)}$.  Better yet [format with $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule says that $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.  For $\cos(2x)$, your $f(x)=\cos(x), g(x)=2x$.  But $(cos(x))'=-\sin(x)$ so it should be $-2\sin(2x)$ in agreement with Alpha

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira:  this is the $g'(x)$ from the chain rule.  Intuitively, $2x$ changes twice as fast as $x$, so the change in $\cos(2x)$ is twice as fast as the change in $\cos(x)$

Comment: Why Alpha transformed \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx} (cos (2x))) into -\frac{1}{2}(sin (2x))(\frac{d}{dx}(2x)) instead of -\frac{1}{2}(-2sin(2x))? I mean, after solving \frac{d}{dx} (cos (2x)) why it still had another derivative to solve?   [EDITED TO INCLUDE LaTeX CODE]

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira:  You need to put the $\LaTeX$ between dollar signs to make it render.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that.  
Why Alpha transformed $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx} (cos (2x)))$ into $-\frac{1}{2}(sin (2x))(\frac{d}{dx}(2x))$ instead of -$\frac{1}{2}(-2sin(2x))$? I mean, after solving $\frac{d}{dx} (cos (2x))$ why it still had another derivative to solve? [RE-REPOSTED TO INCLUDE LaTeX CODE]

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira:  see my first comment on this answer.  It is the $g'(x)$ term

Comment: I'm solving it this way: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx} cos(2x)) + \frac{d}{dx}(C)$, using the chain rule to find the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx} cos(2x))$: $u = 2x$, $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$, $y = cos(u)$, $\frac{dy}{du} = cos(u) = -sin(u)$, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} * \frac{du}{dx}$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = -2*sin(2x)$. (Next steps ommited) Is this right? I'm not getting the same final solution as Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira:  You now have the same solution as Alpha.  Some of the time you had cos instead of sin, and some of the time you were missing the $2$ in front, but this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to differentiate the $\cos$.

If $h(x) = f(g(x))$, the chain rule is $\frac{d}{dx} h(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) \frac{d}{dx} g(x)$.

In your case, $g(x) = 2x, f(x) = \cos (2x)$. The formula gives $-\sin(2x) (2)$.